# specialization being seen as overloading in C++

Tags: c++, templates, opencv

I am a very beginner in templated programming.

I have three templated functions in templated class :

```
// initialize the model (generic template for any other type)
template <typename ImgDataType>
void GrimsonGMMGen<ImgDataType>::InitModel(const cv::Mat& data) // data is an rgb image
{ ... }

template<>
void GrimsonGMMGen<cv::Vec3b>::InitModel(const cv::Mat& data)
{...}

template<>
void GrimsonGMMGen<float>::InitModel(const cv::Mat& data)
{ ... }
```

But I get an error saying there is redeclaration pointing redeclaration of  in  
I remember using such a specialization before and it worked fine. What am I doing wrong here ?

I need to specialize them because of some data structures I am setting up requires the information of what type of image I am using.

Comment: "*there is redeclaration pointing redeclaration of in*"  I don't understand that.  Can you post the complete error(s)?

Comment: Complete error(s) and a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: As an advice, try avoiding function template specialization and prefer overloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do in the question definitely works: Member functions of class templates can be separately specialized (fully). For example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    void print();
};

template <typename T> void Foo<T>::print()
{
    std::cout << "Generic Foo<T>::print()\n";
}

template <> void Foo<int>::print()
{
    std::cout << "Specialized Foo<int>::print()\n";
}

int main()
{
    Foo<char> x;
    Foo<int>  y;

    x.print();
    y.print();
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/5Rl5FQ)